# forcing an unmaintained ActiveRecord adapter to Rails version 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, advantage-database-server, wsl-2

I am working on the "Advantage database server" adapter extension, to try and talk to a legacy database that I have access to (that is still in active usage).

I have updated the "Advantage" Gem so that it works on new/active versions of Ruby https://github.com/t12nslookup/advantage and have seen that my copy of the activerecord-advantage-adapter https://github.com/t12nslookup/activerecord_advantage_adapter works on ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.22

I have been working to try to force it to work with rails 6, and have had reasonable success with a simple "ruby" script that "require"s the gems and accesses the data, but I cannot get the same simple database query to work at the rails console.

I'm running in WSL 2, if it makes any difference (but I don't believe it.

ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux], Rails 6.0.3.3

I have added a rails6 branch to the activerecord-advantage-adapter github project.

Ruby script:

```
jadams@Temp046317:~/code/ais-lims$ more ../testme.rb
require 'rubygems'
gem 'advantage'
gem "activerecord-advantage-adapter"
require "active_record"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'advantage',
  options: 'ServerType=Local|Remote; ReadOnly=True; CommType=TCP_IP; Compression=INTERNET',
  database: '//172.27.176.1:6262/c$/ads/db/'
)

class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'DISCOUNT'
  self.sequence_name = :autogenerated
end

puts Discount.all.inspect
puts Discount.count

jadams@Temp046317:~/code/ais-lims$ ruby ../testme.rb
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Discount >, #<Discount >, #<Discount >, #<Discount >]>
4
```

Rails console:

```
jadams@Temp046317:~/code/ais-lims$ more config/database.yml
development:
  adapter: 'advantage'
  options: 'ServerType=Local|Remote; ReadOnly=True; CommType=TCP_IP; Compression=INTERNET'
  database: '//172.27.176.1:6262/c$/ads/db/'

jadams@Temp046317:~/code/ais-lims$ more app/models/discount.rb
class Discount < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'DISCOUNT'
  self.sequence_name = :autogenerated
end

jadams@Temp046317:~/code/ais-lims$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 728
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.3)
2.7.0 :001 > puts Discount.all.inspect
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass)
2.7.0 :002 > puts Discount.count
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):1
        1: from (irb):2:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass)
```

Any hints on how to debug, or where to find the issue, I'd be grateful.

Jon

Comment: Does Discount.all give you the error? Perhaps the error comes from the inspect method? If you evaluated the console code in a script and got the error you could add debugger and start your search. Good luck.

Comment: A good place to start would be to wrap your call in a ``begin/rescue`` block and print the full backtrace.

Comment: ruby_object contacted me offline and suggested: `def self.testing_method
  byebug
  puts Discount.all.inspect
end

#console
Class.testing_method`
I'm going to try that (I've already started adding "byebug" to the activerecord gem around every point where there is a "to_sym"

Comment: it's something to do with the "columns" ... I'm guessing I need to update that procedure:
Rails 3: "Discount.columns": `irb(main):002:0> Discount.columns.map(&:name)
=> ["CLIENT", "OFFICE", "STARTDATE", "ENDDATE", "TOTAL", "THRESHOLD", "PERCENT"]` Rails 5: `2.7.0 :001 > Discount.columns.map(&:name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass)`

Comment: lol! ... for some reason, although I was performing an "all_cols.uniq" the code was being passed to the next procedure not uniqued ... so there were "rows x cols" columns ... and now it appears to be working (to do counts and get data ... I will have to play with "joins" later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rmlockerd and @ruby_object were both correct in helping to debug, but at the end of the day I'd just written the section of code in a way that didn't work.

debugging was key